# How can a CGI script decode a multipart/form-data

Tags: cgi, multipartform-data

Let's say an HTTP POST request is made with this header

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=...
```

and then, the body is built accordingly.

If I understand correctly, when the web server transmits the request to a CGI application, it sets some environments variables and the body is sent as stdin. So, the CGI app does not have access to the headers (except through some environment variables).

Then, how can a CGI application decode the body (stdin) if it does not have access to the header (Content-Type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CONTENT-TYPE as part of the environment variable that a CGI application has access to. [This link](http://www.users.on.net/~bkgunther/software/multipartforms.html) explains in details how a CGI application can read a multipart form.